# How to customize the calloutAccessoryView of a MKAnnotationView under iOS7?

Tags: ios7, uibutton, mkannotationview, uiappearance

Under iOS6 I did the following to set a custom image for the button of the right callout accessory view:

```c
UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"detaildisclosurebutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
```

That worked very well. Now I am updating the App to iOS7 and I just get a blue circle:
[image: Example]

When I replace the image with a square image, it becomes a square. But it is blue too.

Seems to be the `tintColor`. I tried to set it to nil. I also tried to use `buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom` as `buttonType`, but no success.

Has anyone a solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button type `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure` tints the image by default. Use `UIButtonTypeCustom` instead.

If you really need `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure` (and I can't think of a reason why you would given that you're setting a custom image, you can force your image to use "always original" rendering mode:

[[UIImage imageNamed:@"detaildisclosurebutton.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution!
Nevertheless I am using UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure, because of the correct frame setting here. `imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` helped!